# sed? capitalise all letters before delimiter on each line

Tags: scripting, sed, capitalization

I have a file with random strings before a delimiter of ';', like below.

```
blahDI-blah.john;fdfds;hgdh
DNSK-ECAA.paul;ghdfdgd;fdsd
```

How do I capitalise all letters on each line before the delimiter, so the result will be:

```
BLAHDI-BLAH.JOHN;fdfds;hgdh
DNSK-ECAA.PAUL;ghdfdgd;fdsd
```

Thanks as always!
Steve.

Answer (score 1):

One way with GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/([^;]+)/\U\1/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `awk`

```
awk -F\; '{$1=toupper($1)}1' OFS=\; file
BLAHDI-BLAH.JOHN;fdfds;hgdh
DNSK-ECAA.PAUL;ghdfdgd;fdsd
```